# gulp-webserver serving static files with middleware

Tags: gulp, middleware, e2e-testing

I am trying to serve some static content for a protractor test using gulp in conjunction with gulp-webserver. 
For all routes that start with '/mocks' I want to serve from base path test/mocks (this is the way that the build server is set up - I can't change that).

After much trial and error I got to a configuration that looks like this:

```
gulp.task('serve-e2e', ['build-dev'], function() {
  gulp.src('app').pipe(webserver({
    port: 9001,
    middleware: [
      {route: '/mocks', handle: serveStatic('test/mocks')}
    ]
  }));
});
```

However, that still gives me 404 errors (I've verified the folder location - nothing wrong there) for everything starting with /mocks.

I've even tried this - looking at the code in gulp-webserver, middleware only accepts functions - still to no avail:

```
gulp.task('serve-e2e', ['build-dev'], function() {
  gulp.src('app').pipe(webserver({
    port: 9001,
    middleware: [
      getStatic({route: /^\/mocks/, handle: serveStatic('test/mocks')})
    ]  
  })
);

function getStatic(opts) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    if (parseurl(req).pathname.match(opts.route)) {
      return opts.handle(req, res, next);
    } else {
      return next();
    }
  }
}
```

I'm sure there's a better way to do this but I'm stumped. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that the original route is included in the path which under the above code would result in `test/mocks/mocks`.

While it is still necessary to add the `getStatic` method (gulp-webserver doesn't forward an object to connect - which would be an option if the object contained keys 'route' and 'handle'), the problem was solved for me when I changed it to

```
getStatic({route: /^\/mocks/, handle: serveStatic('test')})
```